# Does locally isometric imply locally diffeomorphic for regular surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\phi: S\rightarrow \tilde{S}$  be a differential map between two regular surfaces. Then $d\phi_p: T_p(S)\rightarrow T_{\phi(p)}(\tilde{S})$. Suppose $(v_1,v_2)=(d\phi_P(v_1),d\phi_p(v_2))$ for any $v_1, v_2\in T_p(S)$. Can we prove that $S$ and $\tilde{S}$ is locally diffeomorphism at $p$

---

I want to prove that by inverse function theorem. Since $(v_1,v_2)=(d\phi_P(v_1),d\phi_p(v_2))$, we can say $d\phi_{p}$ is an isomohphism. Then by inverse function theorem, it is locally diffeomorphic at $p$. Is it correct.

---

Another related question is that there is a theorem any two regular surfaces are locally conformal。 Can we prove by the same argument saying any two regular surfaces are locally diffeomorphic?

Comment: What is the definition of surface you are using?

Comment: @rldias regular surface

Comment: If it is something like "a surface is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ locally diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$" (whatever it means), then the answer to your question is quite trivial.

Comment: @rldias but any two regular surfaces are locally diffeomorphic, it is quite amazing

Comment: Well, it was made to work.. when we chose to model these objects using open sets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (locally), they will all be locally similar.